# Excel operating slow with office 13 and not supporting xlrd (not able to read hyperlink's content)

Tags: python-2.7, ms-office, xlrd

I am facing primarily two problems:

1. I had an excel in `xls` format and I moved it to `xlsm` format. After this, `xlrd` is not able to read the hyperlinks. I have no other option but to use `xlrd`. Any solution?
2. And the `xls` is working too slow with Office 13. I converted it to `xlsm` format too. But still its too slow. Is there anything that can be done with `xlrd`? Actually my python script is used by lot of people to work with excel. So, I cant force each end user to configure `xlsm` (this will be the last option in case no other option is available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For this, the issue is happening because the formatting text flag is not enabled in the case of xlsm. The only solution is to create a new column where we put the sheet name and read it, instead of getting it from the hyperlink.

   ```
   Sub Button1_Click()
       Dim a As Integer
       Dim b As String
       Dim c As Integer

       On Error Resume Next
       For Each hl In Sheets("TPD Sheet").Hyperlinks
           'Get the sheet name
           If Not IsNull(hl) Then
               c = Application.Evaluate(hl.Range.row)
               MsgBox "Aakash" & Application.Evaluate(hl.Range.row)
               Set r = Application.Evaluate(hl.SubAddress)
               'MsgBox "Row number being operated upon -> " & Application.Evaluate(hl.Range.row)
               'Get the cell where the sheet name to be put
               a = Application.Evaluate(hl.Range.row)
               b = Application.Evaluate(hl.Range.Column)


               Set TxtRng = Sheets("MySheet").Cells(a, "D")
               TxtRng.value = r.Parent.name

           End If
       Next hl

   End Sub
   ```
2. Select `disable hardware graphics acceleration` and it will be little faster. Still trying to make it faster.